# My E-Signature I built in PHP/HTML is not working on mobile/tablet/touch device (scrolling)

Tags: javascript, php, html, digital-signature

I created an e-signature area for users to sign that they agree to the terms and conditions before submitting the form. This is then pushed into Microsoft DataVerse backend as an image and stored. There is something wrong because when trying to sign a signature on a mobile/tablet/touch screen device the page is scrolling and not allowing the user to sign correctly.

I've tried supplementing my code with articles I have found online to no avail. I've also been reading other resources to try and figure out why this is happening especially when I have tried :

@media (pointer: coarse) {

body {

```
overflow: hidden; /* Needed to prevent the vertical scroll on touch devices */
```

}

}

Some articles used below:

- https://medium.com/@divbydiv/build-a-signature-pad-in-html-css-js-canvas-bd174d999392
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Signature/Function
- https://codepen.io/yguo/pen/OyYGxQ

Comment: You might want to listen to events such as `touchmove` and use preventDefault, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958030/how-can-i-make-canvas-drawing-work-on-mobile

Comment: Thank you Maxim, taking a look now - appreciate the prompt response <3